# How can I convert PPT files to PNG in PHP without COM?

Tags: php, linux

I need to convert Powerpoint files to PNG in PHP. I can do the conversion with using COM in PHP but COM is only supported on Windows. I need to do this for both Windows and Linux.

I am wondering if someone give me hints about that conversion.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox yes Powerpoint.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of two solutions, a creative one and one that won't work (yet).

The creative one is to convert Powerpoint files to something a bit more Linux friendly, by calling OpenOffice's converters via the command line. And then convert to PNG. Creative, to say the least, and of course it requires that you can install OpenOffice on your server.

The other solution is the [PHPPowerPoint](http://www.phppowerpoint.net) library, currently in alpha. It only works with Microsoft's OpenXML format, and it's of a similar lineage as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) and [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/). I'm pretty sure that it doesn't utilize COM, but since it's still alpha and very recent it most probably won't do exactly what you want. But you can always build upon it.

Both approaches are highly problematic. But so is Powerpoint, so I guess you expected that when you asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I am checking the PHPPowerPoint....+1

Comment: @Arif I used it at some point, but I'm way more familiar with PHPExcel, I can't be certain it will work for you. Hope it does...

Comment: it is mainly used for create PowerPoint. do you think so? May be i need to convert openXML to JPEG.

Comment: @Arif Well I did write in the answer that it wouldn't work (yet). Check out the code, there is a reader in there. But it's still alpha, the main reason I posted it was that you could look at the code and build upon it. AFAIK there isn't a ready made solution (yet).